# Logo recognition with a huge dataset

Tags: image, algorithm, augmented-reality, feature-detection

First of all, thanks for reading my question. I'm beginner in computer vision.

I read a lot but I didn't find any solution.

I have an image and I want to detect logo/logos on it.
Also, I have a whole of images with different logos, all image containing a logo on it and nothing more.

Can you help me with any idea of how to detect logo/logos on an image when I have a whole (thousands) of training sets (known logos set)?

It can be done by using the SURF or SIFT feature detection algorithm for few known logos, by matching the given image with all of the others but I have a huge dataset, and I can't match with all other images.
To try all images in the dataset takes toooooo much time :)

Can be useful any SDK? (it can be even for mobile phones or for desktop also).
Or can I use some multiple algorithms for it?

I found an interesting paper about this question with a SIGMA algorithm, but I can't find any description for these algorithms (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5495345).

I think to detect the features on the images is OK (SIFT, maybe SURF).
But I think the problem is with the big number of known images/logos.
I think it should be stored in a special way.
Ex. made a tree somehow from the thousand of known logos, or to separate them in groups.

Is it possible to do this task?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The thousands of training sets is useful only to test your algorithm, it will not help to analyze a new image.

I made a bit of pattern recognition in the past, I would start this way: look for sharp edges (sharp color transitions too). So an edge filter and statistical analysis about features all located in the same corner. The result of the algorithm will be a number that you will use with your training set.

Since you are doing original reserch be prepared for a long work. If a SDK with a function "ImageHasLogo()" exists yet, you will find it on Google.

Comment: The thousand of images contains a whole of known different logos and not only are for testing. This is to train the program to know thousands of logo types, their shapes, their edges and these will not used for testing. Thanks for your answer. I will search for further possibilities.